# javascript:onClick(); not working in firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

I have this retractable sidebar menu. A javascript onClick is acting as retracting function.
However, it seems to work perfectly fine in Chrome/Safari but not in IE and Firefox. 
It will just return false in IE and firefox and also there is some visual disfigured button in IE & Firefox.

Do click at the image for a better visualisation:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wALFM.jpg

```
 <a href="javascript:onClick();" class="angle icon-double-angle-left"></a>
```

// .JS File page

```
var onClick = function () {
  var sidebar = document.querySelector('.sidebar');
  var body = document.querySelector('.body');
  var angle = document.querySelector('.angle');
  var classNames = document.querySelector('.sidebar').className;
  if(classNames.indexOf('maximized') > -1) {
    sidebar.className = 'sidebar';
    body.className = 'body minimized';
    angle.className = 'angle icon-double-angle-right';
  } else {
    sidebar.className = 'sidebar maximized';
    body.className = 'body';
    angle.className = 'angle icon-double-angle-left';
  }
  return false;
};
```

Comment: Why don't you just do `onclick="onclick"`

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is your function name, onClick.  Declaring a global variable, `var foo = 1`, is the same as saying `window.foo = 1`, so essentially your overriding the `window.onClick` event handler.  Even if that's not the issue in this particular case, it's a confusing function name at best.

Answer (score 1):

It is highly adviced to keep JS and HTML seperate . And no to add or call JS statements or function inline HTML. SO you can bind event handlers on a element through js.

Why JS is given on href so it does not execute its default behavior redirection. Which you can handle by `.preventDefault()` method.

SO if you are using jquery you can do

```
$("a.angle").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); //this will avoid the default behaviour of tag
  //than do other things
});
```

Or if you want to do by pure javascript

```
var clickMethod=function(e){
      e=e||window.event; //for ie <9 support
      e.preventDefault();
      //do something
};

var element=document.queryselectorAll("a.angle");
 /* querySelectorAll method is not supported by ie<8 so use other DOM selector
     method of JS if you want to support ie<8; */

//for ie<10
element.attachEvent('onclick',clickMethod);

//for other browser
element.assignEventListner('click',clickMethod,false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me give u an advice and please try to don't mix the html and JS code, so define something like this in your JS code:

```
var element = document.querySelector('a.angle');
element.onclick = function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
    var sidebar = document.querySelector('.sidebar');
    var body = document.querySelector('.body');
    var angle = document.querySelector('.angle');
    var classNames = document.querySelector('.sidebar').className;

    if(classNames.indexOf('maximized') > -1) {
        sidebar.className = 'sidebar';
        body.className = 'body minimized';
        angle.className = 'angle icon-double-angle-right';
    }
    else {
        sidebar.className = 'sidebar maximized';
        body.className = 'body';
        angle.className = 'angle icon-double-angle-left';
    }
};
```